# Why does TextView in single line elipsized with "end" show boxes?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm using a TextView in Android, what I want to show 1 line in TextView ending with ". " but this give [] type box at the end. I don't know why?  I just want to remvoe this box and only to show text ending with "... "

[image: TextView shown box at end]

Update code for the list_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="85dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:cacheColorHint="#4C7B8D"
android:background="#4C7B8D">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/videoListImage"
    android:src="@drawable/audio_thumbnail60x60"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/next_arrow"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft = "5dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/app_background_color"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"             
            android:maxLines="1" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/row_dis"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1" />
        <TextView
            android:text="$7.50"
            android:id="@+id/audio_price_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textStyle = "bold"
            android:paddingLeft = "12dp"
            android:paddingRight = "12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_round_cornor_background" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/next_arrow"
        android:src="@drawable/next_arrow"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/saved_purchased"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility = "gone"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/saved_purchased"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop ="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the images of "next_arrow"
[image]

Here is the code I am using the getView() in adapter.

```
  String discription = listData.getDescription();
    if (discription != null && discription.length() > 0) {
        if (textViewDis != null) {
            textViewDis.setTypeface(titleFont);
            Log.e("data", ""+discription);
            discription.replaceAll("\r\n", "");
            textViewDis.setText(discription);
        }
    }
```

Here is the actual String of description to be display.

> Andrew and Stephanie Tidwell candidly share their success story in this business. This story will help everyone listening realize that no one is perfect, even in a second generation business. This is a streaming audio file.

Still have some issue? I can update question more.

Comment: I don't see any problem with your layout. Where does the value for your TextView come from? Is it possible that you get a carriage return / line feed sign attached to your string, somehow?

Comment: Oh yes that might be a problem... I want not considering it. How to resolve it?

Comment: Try to apply `String.replaceAll("\r\n", "")` to your String.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Quoting myself from [one of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android):

> Android's TextView class has the built-in ability to "ellipsize" text,
>   truncating it and adding an ellipsis if the text is longer than the available
>   space. You can use this via the android:ellipsize attribute, for example.
>   This works fairly well, at least for single-line text.
>   The ellipsis that Android uses is not three periods. Rather it uses an actual
>   ellipsis character, where the three dots are contained in a single glyph.
>   Hence, any font that you use that you also use the "ellipsizing" feature will
>   need the ellipsis glyph.
>
> Beyond that, though, Android pads out the string that gets rendered on-screen, such that the length (in characters) is the same before and after
>   "ellipsizing". To make this work, Android replaces one character with the
>   ellipsis, and replaces all other removed characters with the Unicode
>   character 'ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE' (U+FEFF). This means the
>   "extra" characters after the ellipsis do not take up any visible space on
>   screen, yet they can be part of the string.
>
> However, this means any custom fonts you use for TextView widgets that
>   you use with android:ellipsize must also support this special Unicode
>   character. Not all fonts do, and you will get artifacts in the on-screen
>   representation of your shortened strings if your font lacks this character
>   (e.g., rogue X's appear at the end of the line).

Comment: Thank you very much sir for your time. I got it. But how to resolve this issue? Have you solve it?

Comment: @Arslan: Use a built-in font. Or, fix the font to contain the missing U+FEFF glyph. Or, use a font that already has this glyph.

Comment: @Manu-iAndyDev : Yes I change the font. You can use built in fonts as well.

Answer (score 6):

I have bumped into the same problem when was trying to use custom "MetaPro-Medium.otf" as font for `TextView` with a 
`android:singleLine="true"`.
The box at the end of the string was really annoying.

I found no way how to solve this problem in Android, but at the same time found following work around.

1. I have installed "FontLab Studio v5.04"
2. Opened my font
3. Selected one of symbols I was not going to use
4. Menu->Glyph->Rename Glyph
5. Changed the name and unicode index from it`s original value to "FEFF" (Thank CommonsWare)
6. Double click on selected symbol and then remove all lines this symbol was created from.
7. Menu->File->Generate Font->save as type otf

As a result I got updated font and problem gone away.

Answer (score 3):

Arslan, your layout is working fine in my case, I have tested the same with:

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/row_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:ellipsize="end"             
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="This is the demo testing demo testing This is the demo testing demo testing"/>
```

... and getting the exact output as you want "one line ended with ..." and box should be removed. So I think there may be a something wrong with any character or text you are setting.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Let me check it again. I this the ">" image then may be causing problem.

Answer (score 2):

I face the same issue (show boxes([])) for some special symbols when I try to show content which is coming from webservice url even, I don't use android:ellipsize. then I replace code from

```
textview.settext(content);
```

to

```
textview.settext(Html.fromHtml(content));
```

working fine.

Comment: Don' know why this isn't working for me.  Is there any special time you set the textview is it in onCreate?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I was running into this issue and instead of changing the font or using setText I just added scrollHorizontally as false and it fixed the extra box character

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:scrollHorizontally="false"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: It seems that this solution does not work after I recompiled.  What does work is not to use ellipsize.  The only way so far I have found to make this work is to edit the font.  I don't have Fontlab Studio and can't afford $900.  So I will remove it for now and make my own version of ellipsize later.

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem which i was facing in my project where in i was using a font type for the text view. few font types have these problem of making the ... appear as [] at the last. The problem would be solved if u try changing the font.