# When I put a long string on textView,Why some chars looks like these photos??

Tags: android, textview

I am testing it on Galaxy S2,there is no problem on it. But some devices looks like These screenshots- samsung Galaxy Note -.

What should I do? I cant find any topic about it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6492931/459413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextView ...
....
android:ellipsize="none"
..></TextView>
```

You need to set the `ellipsize` to none for that textview and there will be no "..."

Second thing this only happens when you have set your textview to `SingleLine =  true`, so if you want to streatch your textview to multiline based on the text size then remove the singleline.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem. But I cant understand that what is [][][][][] after ... ?? :)

Answer (score 0):

this is because the width of the textView is  less and you are trying to add characters more than that,, 
1) try to add more width to the textView 
you can [check out here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aminWidth) how to set width

Comment: hmm, I cant add more width textview. Why it looks like [][][][] ??? Also it puts a lot of '.' ?

Comment: To let you know there is more text there beyond the end of the button.

Comment: you can change the font size of textView and  also can remove the bold.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `android:layout_width = "wrap_content"`.

Alternatively you can use `android:layout_width = "45dp"` (or your defined width) and set the `android:maxLines = "2"`. This will wrap the test in two lines and you will find what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

instead of taking android:singleLine in XMl file you can declare it in your java code where you define your textView.

```
text.setSingleLine(true);
```

or in XML file

```
   android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
```