# android textview singleLine="true" square bracket

Tags: android, textview

Can someone tell me, why there is a square bracket at the end row which shown in the red circles if TextView has property `single_line="true"` and cyrillic text is set?

[image: Applicaton]

Comment: Can you give us some code/xml ?

Comment: It seems like broken symbol (encoding problem). Do you have new lines at the end (a file with all menus), are they just `\n` (unix) or windows `\r\n`? How do you shorten the strings with hellips (...) - alrorithm?

Comment: Do you use a custom font?

Comment: please try this.android:ellipsize="start"

Comment: Yes, I am use custom font - EUROPE_DEMI

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I've also used custom font - Arial. Did you find any solution??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492074/why-does-textview-in-single-line-elipsized-with-end-show-boxes